# Loading an input file and creating vectors and matrices in Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, octave

I'm required to load my data into Octave and create a vector `A` containing the first column of data and a matrix `B` containing the rest of my data. I've loaded my data into Octave with the `load('wine.dat')` command. I've also created a vector with the first column of data for vector `A`, but I'm having trouble pulling the second column and the rest of the data and storing into a matrix.

My data set is similar to the following:

```
1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050
2,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185
2,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480
3,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735
3,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,1450
```

`A = dlmread('wine.dat', [1])` created a vector for the first column of data. How would I create a matrix for the second column and the remainder of the data set?

Comment: I think a better (easier) approach would be to read all of the data into the matrix B, and then create A from the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data file `wine.dat` contains exactly the sample text you included above, then you're dealing with comma-separated numeric data and the easiest choice for loading it will be [`csvread`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFcsvread). For example:

```
B = csvread('wine.dat');
```

This will load all the data into a 6-by-14 matrix `B`. Now you can create your final `A` and `B` matrices with some simple [indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Index-Expressions.html):

```
A = B(:, 1);   % Copy the first column of B into A
B(:, 1) = [];  % Remove the first column of B
```